# Variable 'questions' Not Defined in JavaScript despite Correct Data Retrieval from Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am facing an issue with my web application where I retrieve data from a database and display it on a web page. I have a variable named 'questions' that holds questions retrieved from the database. When I log this variable to the console, I can see the data properly. However, when I try to use 'questions' in my JavaScript code, it throws an error stating that 'questions' is not defined.

I'm using the Express.js framework for my backend, EJS templates for rendering, and MySQL for the database. The structure of my database tables appears to be correct.

```
// JavaScript code in my EJS template
<section class="flex section-quiz">
    <div class="w-100 text-align">
        <p id="text-question"><%= questions[currentQuestionIndex].question %></p>
    </div>
    <ul class="w-100 text-align">
        <% for (let i = 0; i < reponses.length; i++) { %>
        <li class="btn-opaque">
            <label for="<%= reponses[i].id %>"></label>
            <input type="radio" name="reponse" class="btn-radio" id="<%= reponses[i].id %>" value="<%= reponses[i].id %>" />
            <%= reponses[i].texte_reponse %></li>
        <% } %>
    </ul>
</section>
```

```
app.get("/quiz/:id", (request, response) => {
    const id = parseInt(request.params.id);

    // Utilisation de Promises pour gérer plusieurs requêtes SQL de manière asynchrone
    Promise.all([
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connect.query(`SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id_quizzes=${id}`, (err, questionsResult) => {
                if (err) reject(err);
                resolve(questionsResult);
            });
        }),
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connect.query(`SELECT * FROM réponses WHERE id_quizzes=${id}`, (err, reponsesResult) => {
                if (err) reject(err);
                resolve(reponsesResult);
            });
        }),
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connect.query(`SELECT * FROM quizzes WHERE id=${id}`, (err, quizResult) => {
                if (err) reject(err);
                resolve(quizResult);
            });
        })
    ])
    .then((value) => {
        console.log("Résultats des requêtes:", value);
        response.render("quiz", {
            pseudo: request.session.pseudo,
            questions: value[0],
            reponses: value[1], 
            quiz: value[2][0], 
            currentQuestionIndex: 0,
            score: 0,
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Une erreur s'est produite :", err);
        throw err;
    });
});
```

The js script :

```
<script>
    const currentQuestionIndex = <%= currentQuestionIndex %>;
    let score = <%= score %>;

    console.log(questions[0])
  
    const suivantButton = document.getElementById('suivant');
    suivantButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // Récupérer la réponse sélectionnée
      const selectedResponseId = document.querySelector('input[name="reponse"]:checked');
      if (selectedResponseId) {
        const selectedResponse = reponses.find(response => response.id === parseInt(selectedResponseId.value));
  
        // Vérifier si la réponse est correcte
        if (selectedResponse.est_correcte) {
          score++;
        }
        
        currentQuestionIndex++;
  
        // Vérifier s'il y a encore des questions à afficher
        if (currentQuestionIndex < questions.length) {
          // Afficher la prochaine question
          afficherQuestion(questions[currentQuestionIndex]);
        } else {
          // Afficher le score final
          afficherScoreFinal(score);
        }
      }
    });
  
    function afficherQuestion(question) {
      // Mettre à jour le contenu de la question et les réponses
      document.getElementById('text-question').textContent = question.question;
      const reponsesList = document.querySelector('ul');
      reponsesList.innerHTML = '';
      question.reponses.forEach((reponse) => {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        const input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
        input.setAttribute('name', 'reponse');
        input.setAttribute('value', reponse.id);
        const label = document.createElement('label');
        label.textContent = reponse.texte_reponse;
        li.appendChild(input);
        li.appendChild(label);
        reponsesList.appendChild(li);
      });
    }
  
    function afficherScoreFinal(score) {
      // Afficher le score final 
      document.getElementById('score').textContent = score;
    }
  
    // Afficher la première question
    afficherQuestion(questions[currentQuestionIndex]);
  </script>
```